# display http in place of https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, ssl, https

I am using an MVC application and hosted on server but there is some problem in SSl. So url is marked as Not Secure

[image]

So untill my problem has been solved from go daddy i want to show the url as http. So how can i do this i mean my url should be like http://www.indianmuslimwedding.com so that Not Secure in url should not be display to user.

Comment: Maybe mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Your site is marked as 'not secure' because the browser does. This is a warning for users that your site is unencrypted. Maybe try this: **[Redirect HTTP to HTTPS Godaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828)**